# jQuery ajax SOAP multipart response pdf

Tags: jquery, ajax, soap, mime, multipart

I am sending a jQuery ajax request with `data:xml`and`Content-Type:text/xml` and getting following response:

```
--MIME_boundary
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope> .............</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
--MIME_boundary
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

.... pdf binary data .....
```

As i understand the reponse is a multipart with an attachment ... but how can i extract the soap part and the pdf raw data part individually and use the binary data to build this pdf? Thanx for any help.

keeping in view also this: http://www.w3.org/TR/SOAP-attachments#SOAPReferenceToAttachements

UPDATE:
after a bit of research, summing up of lots of different responses there are the following issues and questions that arise for me:

- Ajax - jquery .ajax() function- handles only text/xml response, thats why it does not handle binary data (read it somewhere). But if i am getting multipart with -> Content-Type: application/pdf -> I AM getting the binary data in it.
- The binary data could be converted to base64 and then use the html5 data: -> but that has complex issues where every browser behaves differently with it.

Now, my conclusion would be:

- Just make an ajax request, get the URL path and download the file directly from the server by using window.location.href

Correct if i am wrong here: jQuery Ajax cannot handle multipart MIME reponses??

Answer (score 0):

AJAX uses UTF-8 encoding, therefore it cannot support binary data transfer. You need to Base64 encode your binary data, then decode it on the other end. You need to set your headers accordingly.

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Description: somefile.pdf
Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename="somefile.pdf"

....then your Base-64 data blob ...
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer, ill keep that in mind. But i wanted actually to know how i can extract the second part of the soap response. Because, using the jquery .ajax() function although it gives me the above mentioned response it generates an error - maybe because it cannot handle the multipart reponse ?

Comment: Ajax isn't intended for file transfers.